# Proof verification: $\lim_{x\to2} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

**Is either of the following methods correct?**

Prove
$$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}$$

**First Method**

**Preliminary Analysis:**

We know that $a = 2$, $L= \frac{1}{2}$, and $f(x)= \frac{1}{x}$. By the precise definition of limit we have the following:
$$ 
0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon\\
0<|x-2|<\delta \implies \left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}\right|<\varepsilon \implies \left|\frac{2}{2x}-\frac{x}{2x}\right| <\varepsilon \implies \left|\frac{2-x}{2x}\right| <\varepsilon \\
\implies \left|\frac{-(-2+x)}{2x}\right| <\varepsilon \implies \left|\frac{x-2}{2x}\right| <\varepsilon \implies \frac{\left|x-2\right|}{\left|2x\right|} <\varepsilon \implies \left|x-2\right|<\varepsilon \left|2x\right|
$$

let $\delta = \varepsilon\left|2x\right|$ but we need to simplify it further because delta should be in terms of $\varepsilon$ only.

Assume $|x-a| < 1$

$$ |x-2| < 1 \implies -1 <x -2<1 \implies -1+2<x<1+2 \implies 1<x<3$$

Then we have to simplify $|2x|$ as well, which ends up being

$$ 2<2x<6 \implies -6<2x<6 \implies |2x| <6$$

Now consider the inequality we discovered, specifically, $\left|x-2\right|<\varepsilon \left|2x\right|$ this inequality is also valid for $\left|x-2\right|<\varepsilon\cdot6$.

Let $\delta = \min{\{1, \varepsilon\cdot6}\}$

**Proof:**

Given $\varepsilon > 0$ let $\delta = \min{\{1, \varepsilon\cdot6}\}$ if $ 0<|x-2|<\delta \implies |x-2|<1 \implies 1 <x < 3 \implies 2 < 2x < 6 \implies - 6 < 2x < 6 \\ \implies |2x| < 6$

We also have  $|x - 2| < \varepsilon \cdot6$.

$$ 
\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}\right|\implies \left|\frac{2}{2x}-\frac{x}{2x}\right| \implies \left|\frac{2-x}{2x}\right| \\
\implies \left|\frac{-(-2+x)}{2x}\right|\implies \left|\frac{x-2}{2x}\right| \implies \frac{\left|x-2\right|}{\left|2x\right|} < \frac{\varepsilon \cdot 6}{6} = \varepsilon
$$

By the precise definition of limit $$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}$$

**Second Method**

**Proof by Definition/Property**:

By the direct substitution property if $f$ is a polynomial or a rational function and $a$ is in the domain of $f$, then

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$$

Then by the direct substituon property of limit: $$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}$$

**Are either of the above methods correct?** (*I am putting the question here as well in case someone misses it*)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Use `$\to$` for $\to$.

Comment: @Vincent Are either of the following methods correct? It is also indicated at the very top.

Comment: Look at the first sentence, @Vincent.

Comment: The first proof is a  little bit overkill in the level of detail between the steps, but is nonetheless accurate.  The second proof, needs one small detail....The statement is true for rational functions when the denominator is non-zero.

Comment: @DougM Thank you sir...I think I went overkill because a lot of people here are a lot further in their mathematical thinking than I am, and I did not want to leave a room for misinterpretation on my part. It also helped me show my thinking process so if there is something missing, someone would surely point it out.

Comment: Better too much detail than to skip over the important bits.  The rule I was given as a student, the proof should be written is such a way that the you of two weeks ago would be able to follow it.

Comment: About writing: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/advice-on-writing-papers/take-advantage-of-the-english-language/

Answer (score 2):

`proof-verification:`

> `(1)`Given $\varepsilon > 0$`,` let $\delta = \min{\{1, 6\varepsilon}\}$`.`
>
> `(2)`if $ 0<|x-2|<\delta \implies |x-2|<1 \implies 1 <x < 3 \implies 2 < 2x < 6 \implies - 6 < 2x < 6 \\ \implies |2x| < 6$
>
> `(3)`We also have  $|x - 2| < \varepsilon \cdot6$.
>
> $$ 
> \left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}\right|\implies \left|\frac{2}{2x}-\frac{x}{2x}\right| \implies \left|\frac{2-x}{2x}\right| \\
> \implies \left|\frac{-(-2+x)}{2x}\right|\implies \left|\frac{x-2}{2x}\right| \implies \frac{\left|x-2\right|}{\left|2x\right|} < \frac{\varepsilon \cdot 6}{6} = \varepsilon
> $$

`The writing of these line 2 and 3 are terrible. One should not write those confusing big "implication" arrows for doing simple algebra. Moreover, (3) is incorrect:` $|x-2|<6\varepsilon$ `and` $|2x|<6$ `do` *`not`* `imply that`
$$
\frac{|x-2|}{|2x|}<\frac{6\varepsilon}{6}.
$$

> By the <s>precise</s> definition of limit, $$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}$$

---

You want to get the estimate like
$$
\frac{|x-2|}{|2x|}<\epsilon.
$$
The intuition is as follows. On the one hand, $|x-2|$ can be as small as possible if $x$ is close to $2$. One the other hand, when $x$ is close to $2$, the quantity $\frac{1}{|2x|}$ is *bounded* by some positive real number. Thus together, one can get $\frac{|x-2|}{|2x|}$ as small as one wants when $x$ is close to $2$.

Now we turn the intuition to a rigorous proof. Given $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta = \min\{1,\epsilon\}$. If $0<|x-2|<\delta$, then $1<x<3$, which implies that
$$
\frac{1}{|2x|}<1 \tag{1}
$$
On the other hand, by the definition of $\delta$, we also have
$$
|x-2|<\epsilon.\tag{2}
$$
Combining (1) and (2), we have the desired inequality
$$
\frac{|x-2|}{|2x|}<\epsilon. 
$$

Answer (score 0):

For the second method, it is ok since the rational function is continuous on it definition area.

Answer (score 0):

The first is incorrect.

$$|x-2|<1\implies 1 <x <3\implies $$
$$\frac {1}{6}<\frac {1}{2x}<\frac {1}{2} $$

thus

$$|\frac {1}{x}-\frac {1}{2}|<\frac {|x-2|}{2} $$

if $|x-2|<1$ and $|x-2|<2\epsilon $ then $$|\frac {1}{x}-\frac {1}{2}|<\epsilon $$

we take $$\delta=\min (1,2\epsilon) $$

Comment: So let me link the document that I used as a learning tool to come up with the first proof and perhaps you can point what I missed? Its the 4th proof. https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~yosenl/math/epsilon-delta.pdf

Comment: @Iamlearningmath Your case is not in the document.